# Select Multiple rows from Data Table and Save in GoogleSheets

Tags: r, datatable, shiny, dt

I'm working on an application that pulls data from an API. My next objective is to click on multiple rows in the data table and save all the selected rows in the connected Google Sheet, that's where I'm stuck. I don't know how to select data in a way that it gets stored in another variable which I can later send to Google Sheets or another database.

```
library(shiny)
library(jsonlite)
library(tidyverse)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)

ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "APPLICATION"),
    dashboardSidebar(
        sidebarMenu(
            menuItem('Menu', tabName='menu',
                     menuSubItem('Select Data', tabName='tab1'),
                     menuSubItem('Selected Data', tabName='tab2')
            )
        )
    ),

    dashboardBody(

        tabItems(
            tabItem(tabName='tab1',
                    textInput('usernameinput', 'Username:', 'Username'),
                    actionButton("search", "Search", class = "btn btn-info"),
                    br(),
                    tags$div(tags$h3(tags$b(" Select Data",align="middle",style="color: rgb(57,156,8)"))),
                    br(),
                    DT::dataTableOutput('table')
            ),
            tabItem(tabName='tab2'
            )
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

    observeEvent(input$search, {
    url <- paste0("https://API-LINK/", input$usernameinput)
    link <- fromJSON(url, flatten=T)
    data <- as.data.frame(link$results)


    output$table <- renderDataTable({

        DT::datatable(data,selection = "multiple",

                      extensions = c('Buttons', 'ColReorder', 'FixedHeader', 'Scroller'),
                      rownames=FALSE,
                      options=list(dom = 'Bfrtip',
                                   searching = T,
                                   pageLength = 25,
                                   searchHighlight = TRUE,
                                   colReorder = TRUE,
                                   fixedHeader = TRUE,
                                   filter = 'bottom',
                                   buttons = c('copy', 'csv','excel', 'print'),
                                   paging    = TRUE,
                                   deferRender = TRUE,
                                   scroller = TRUE,
                                   scrollX = TRUE,
                                   scrollY = 700
                                   ))
                                }) 

    })
    # print the selected indices
    output$selected = renderPrint({
        s = input$ListingID
        if (length(s)) {
            cat('These rows were selected:\n\n')
            cat(s, sep = ', ')
        }
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding accessing and manipulating the data...

1 - Are you trying to create an application that a client/user can use or are you trying to gather the data for your own use/analysis?

2 - Is the only way to the data via the API?

3 - Is the data in a MS SQL database or MySQL or are you scraping data or what?

4 - Can you logon to the db and use a tool such as phpMyAdmin or MySQL workbench?

5 - Using the API can you get the data in any form... like display on your screen or download it or what?

Comment: 1.Its for my use, 2.API is the only option, 3.Data is in JSON 4. No 5.Yes, you can conver the JSON data in any form, for eg. CSV, Excel, how ever you want

Comment: Get the data and download it as a csv file.
Manually import it into Google Sheets.
Or create a Google Sheet Macro via Macros to memorize the keystrokes... or use Apps Script

Comment: The idea behind creating an R Shiny application is to streamline all the work which includes downloading or running macros for different processes. I'm looking for a solution that helps me Select the multiple rows from the data table and store data in a variable to be sent to Google sheets. "Selecting Multiple rows" and storing them in a variable is the only part.

Comment: My bad.  I typically only write raw code with Notepad++ and am mostly unfamiliar with all the software shortcut tools out there. Hopefully someone else  will jump and and give you a hand.